# Create JSONReader object with CipherInputStream in Java

Tags: java, json, encryption

I encrypted contents in JSON file using CipherOutputStream. But I have trouble when decrypting it.

I use [com.google.gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to deal with JSON file, and [Cipher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) class to encrypt-decrypt.

This is my code for decrypting content in my JSON file

```
InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, Encryption.get_decrypt_cipher());
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(cis, "UTF-8"));
```

The trouble comes when the `reader` cannot read the `JsonObject` when I called `reader.beginObject()` and thus my program returns a `RuntimeException`.

Can you help me with this problem? Cause I don't really understand how `CipherInputStream` and `JsonReader` work.

Comment: Your posted code looks normal. When it comes to encryption usually the Cipher initialization for encryption and decryption is the problem. Edit your post and add the Cipher initialization code. Note that you have to use the same key for encryption and decryption (nor randomly generated key)!

Comment: Related: I suggest you first just read the cipherinput as text, and look at it manually to see if it looks like JSON (in which case the decryption is good but there may be a problem with your JSON formatting) or if it looks like random gibberish _or_ truncated (in which case the crypto is bad).